# Show that $P = (f(x))$ is a maximal ideal of $F(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, irreducible-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $F$ be a field and $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$. Prove that $P = (f(x))$ is maximal in $F[x]$.

(Here is what I know: $f(x) \neq 0 \wedge f(x) \not \in U(F[x])$, since $f(x)$ is irreducible.

Suppose, $P = (f(x))$ is not a maximal. Then, let $I = (g(x))$ be an ideal of $F(x)$ such that ${P \subseteq I \subseteq F[x]}$...(not sure there. What to show when something is not a maximal ideal?) Then, $g(x) \mid f(x) \Rightarrow f(x) = g(x)h(x)$...Here, I am trying to contradict the fact that $f(x)$ is irreducible but not sure how to do so. Any help would be much appreciated.

I know I can quote some theorem to prove what I am doing. But, I also need to know how to prove it directly.

Comment: Just show that neither $g$ nor $h$ is a unit an you're done.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure how to do that. But here is something I thought: Suppose $deg(g(x)) = 0 \Rightarrow g(x) \in U(K[x]) \Rightarrow g(x) = 1$. But then $I = (1) = K[x]$, which is a contradiction. (can I say that)?

Comment: Sort of...you should say $(g(x))=(1)$.

Comment: Yes that it a good argument. It is half of what you need, essentially.

Comment: You have to write F[x] instead of F(x) (this last notation is for the corresponding field)

Comment: Sorry, I meant F[x] not K[x].

Answer (score 1):

First, you need the inclusions to be proper. Likely, you know this but you should also write it, so write: ${P \subsetneq I \subsetneq F(x)}$.

Second, when you say $I = (g(x))$ you use that $F[X]$ is a PID. Otherwise you could not just assume that $I$ is a principal ideal. Again, this is likely fine as you should have seen the result that it is a PID, but you should be aware that you need that and say so.

Then, you do the right thing. You say that you get $f(x)= g(x)h(x)$. Then, since $f(x)$ is irreducible. One of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ must be a unite/invertible. If it is $g$, then $I = F[X]$ contradiction. If it is $h$, then $(f(x))= (g(x))$, contradiction.

You can also set up the last step differently. Like so: Since $I \neq F[X]$, we have $g(x)$ is not invertible. Since $(f(x)) \neq (g(x))$ we get $h$ is not invertible. A contradiction to $f$ irreducible.

Comment: That makes sense. And, for the part, where I wrote $P\subseteq I \subseteq F[x]$, I can write $P \neq I \neq F[x]$, right? So, the contradiction would be a bit easier to catch.

Comment: No you cannot write that. You should write what I said, obviously. :-) If you just say $P \neq I$ then you do not get anymore that $g(x) \mid f(x)$. It could be an altogether different ideal. You want to assume that $P$ is not maximal. thus you must assume that there is an ideal strictly in between $P$ and the full ring. You need inclusion and they must be propose. (For $I \neq F[X]$ this would kind off work, as $I \subset F[x]$ is clear anyway. But for the other you must be careful. )

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what was I thinking :)